# How to generate file contents automatically for lab testing

Tags: c#, .net, testing

I need to generate disk structure with several files with "random" data to test the performance of our application. I have several restrictions:

- Each time I generate the data must be always the same, even different executions.
- The data must be big (> 8GB)
- The resources used to generate the data must be lightweight (for example a zip with 8 Gb is not valid for me)
- I would like the data look like source code, or at lease something human readable. The reason is that our software manages source code, and it compress data so I need to generate data as similar as possible to the reality.

Well the first thing it came to my head is making a zip of a source code repository from github, for example, but this is not an option because we need to test in the Amazon cloud. We also don't want to download each time 8Gb of data, or upload the zip file.

So I created a metadata file with a disk structure tree and a program that populates data in files. The metadata file looks like this:

```
\dir1 -1
\dir1\file1.data 1435
\dir2\ -1
\dir2\file2.data 44513
```

The number next to the path is -1 for directories and the desired file size for files in bytes.

So, I can generate easyly a disk structure with random data. This is not valid for me because each time the file contents is different.

Do you know any library, example, method, technique ... to perform this task?

Comment: Couldn't you just seed the Randomiser?

Comment: if it's ok to create a files structure on your disk, why do not just have a copy of some bi repository and avoid generating the code every time you need. ?